# How to make multiple instances of foreign key work in one row

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Hello people and fellow SQL programmers.

I have been trying to work out a reality model that is situated in Industry.
The client, that the database is ordered by states that:
There are multiple different job locations/offices where his employees work. Each workplace/office has a set number of people that can work here - minimum and maximum. For each workplace there is a group of people that consists of at least 2 people and max at 4 people. There can be only one group stationed in one work place at a time. There are also a few specifications for the group such as - there are no leaders among them - everybody is equal. A certain worker can only be assigned to only one group at a time. And there is to be an evidence in history who and where worked and for how long.

I have been trying to work the table design with its attributes for quite some time but it seems to me that everything i have done so far has some serious holes and is quite messy. I would very much appreciate any feedback and advice from you guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and describe its problems.

Comment: Basically i have made the tables as the Client ordered: "Worker" has (ID_W, Date_of_birth, Name, Surename), then "Work_place" (ID_W_P, Address, Pay_for_hour, Max_number_of_people, Min_number_of_people, Type) then the last table "Shift / wok_goup" consists of (ID_W_G, Date, Start_of_Shift, End_of_Shift, Min_number_of_people, Max_number_of_people, Name)

Comment: The problem is that i cannot work out how to make it that the number of people in the Shift can range from 2 to 4. So the problem will start with that i need to make multiple instances of one foreign key that belongs to workers in the Workers´ table point to the Shift table multiple times (2 to 4 times) that is in my opinion really messy and can cause real problems, since you can have a shift that consists of only from 2 people and then at the same time 3 or 4 people. How to make this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have two entities: `employee` and `office`. These will require two tables:

```
employee: id, name, whatever_else
office: id, desc, min_employees, max_employees, whatever_else
```

Theoretically the relationship between these two entities is `one-to-many`, because you say each employee can only be assigned to a single office at a time, so you could add a `office_id` foreign key to the `employee` table.

Having to keep track of the history however means that each employee may have multiple associations with the offices, thus making the relationship `many-to-many`. You will then need another table to model it:

```
employeeOffice: employee_id, office_id, start_date, end_date
```

With this model the queries I imagine you'll need to perform would be quite easy; as an example, finding how many employees are currently assigned to each office would be

```
select  t1.id, t1.desc, count(distinct t2.employee_id)
from    office t1
join    employeeOffice t2
on      t1.id = t2.office_id
where   t2.end_date is null
group by t1.id, t1.desc
```

**Edit**

Take this sample data as an example

```
employee
id | name
1  | name1
2  | name2
3  | name3
4  | name4
5  | name5
6  | name6
7  | name7

office
id | desc
1  | office1
2  | office2

employeeOffice
employee_id | office_id | start_date   | end_date
1           | 2         | '01-01-2107' | '31-01-29107'
1           | 1         | '01-02-2107' |
2           | 1         | '01-01-2107' |
3           | 1         | '01-01-2107' |
4           | 1         | '01-01-2107' |
5           | 2         | '01-01-2107' | '01-03-2107'
6           | 2         | '01-01-2107' |
7           | 2         | '01-01-2107' |
```

This would mean that employee 1 spent one month in office 2 and then was assigned to office 1. Employee 5 after two months resigned (or was fired), because there's no record for him with empty `end_date`.

The example query above would give you

```
id | desc    | count
1  | office1 | 4
2  | office2 | 2
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for this explanation but i get the relations (or i think i do) but i have more trouble with viewing the Worker-Shift relation. In each shift there is from 2 to 4 Workers so how am i going to make a row that has variable number of Worker_ID each referencing a unique worker?

Comment: You don't do that. If you have an application layer, I would check if an employee can be added to a shift from there (counting how many are already assigned before inserting), otherwise you could use a trigger that does that check before the insertion

Comment: So the tables would be as you stated before, ok? And then there would be the employeeOffice table that you mentioned. But from what i see in that table there is only one possible worker to be placed - or do i get that wrong? Because i think that the employee_id would need to be there 2 times, or is that wrong too? I am just trying to look and think of the way to insert the data into it to make the row complete - i just need 2 workers in the employeeOffice table /Shift table at the start, because from what you said i can add them later.

Comment: Ohhh, I see now. Pardon my stupidity i was so focused on making the Worker_ID part of the Shift that i forgot i could just assign them in the same office with the same start date. Thank you friend, you have opened my eyes!

Comment: Glad it helped! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.